# bash shell: how to rename files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just want to rename all the *.a file to *.a.b in current directory and subdirs, how to do it in shell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.a' -print0 | xargs -0 -IZZ mv ZZ ZZ.b
```

This should handle filenames with spaces and / or newlines. It also doesn't rename directories  (the other solution doing find would). If you want it to be case-insensitive, use "-iname" instead of "-name"

Answer (score 2):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$ ruby -e 'Dir["**/*.a"].each{|x|File.file?x && File.rename(x,"#{x}.b")}'
```

In a shell script (at least Bash 4)

```sh
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for file in **/*.a
do
 echo mv "${file}" "${file}.b"
done
```

Comment: Sorry, it appears that my browser was displaying a different answer before. The version I'm seeing now is definitely recursive. This also seems like a great solution!

Answer (score 1):

To rename `<files>` with that, `rename 's/\.a$/.a.b/' <files>`.  Doing so recursively will just take a bit of looping.

(or use `*`, `*/*`, `*/*/*`, `*/*/*/*`, etc. for the files)

Comment: If bash 4, then `shopt -s globstar` and use `**`

Answer (score 1):

Try the script below:

```
for file in `find . -name '*.a'`; do mv $file $file.b; done
```

Comment: sorry, but that won't handle spaces and newlines in file names correctly - you might want to try using -print0 and xargs -0 instead.

Comment: Or: find . -name '*.a' | while read -r x; do mv "$x" "$x.b"; done